# How to remove Server list of Docker(Project Interpreter) on Pycharm

Tags: docker, pycharm

server list is not available but that still remainding.

how to remove 'server list'?

[[image]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mac users:

Open the terminal and type

> sudo nano
>   /Users/$(whoami)/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2016.3/options/remote-servers.xml

Probably you need to modify the paths pycharm version to your current one.

Remove the remote server you don't need anymore, save changes and restart pycharm

Comment: For Linux users the file is ~/.PyCharm2017.1/config/options/remote-servers.xml

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the **Docker integration** plugin is enabled first. Then edit the Docker server list by going to

> **Preferences** > **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Docker**

[image: Docker servers list]